# vi - how to add specific characters at the end of line

Tags: vi

I would like to know if is possible in vi to add at the end of a line some specific character of ther line itself.
Example:
Before

```
    donald /mount/donald_01
    mickey /mount/mickey_01
    mickeym /mount/mickey_02
```

After some :%s%"last two characters"%"last two characters"/"last two characters"% command

```
    donald /mount/donald_01/01
    mickey /mount/mickey_01/01
    mickeym /mount/mickey_02/02
```

Thanks
gb

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about vi, so that might not be useful, but in VIM you can do something like that:

```
donald /mount/donald_01
mickey /mount/mickey_01
mickeym /mount/mickey_02
```

`%s%\(..\)$%\1/\1%` will give you the following output:

```
donald /mount/donald_01/01
mickey /mount/mickey_01/01
mickeym /mount/mickey_02/02
```

The syntax is very close to that of `sed`. You might want to learn this.

**EDIT**: I just got to work and tried it with an old vi version. It works.